# Pygame, the window becomes irresponsive when I try to click it

Tags: python, pygame, window

I'm working on a game with Pygame and it was going well...until it decided to not respond. Here's my code:(sorry if the formatting doesn't work im new to stackoverflow)

```
#MODULES USED (use from to make calling functions easier)
from random import *
from pygame import *
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
from time import *

#INITIALISE THE PYGAME WINDOW
pygame.event.pump()
screen = display.set_mode([500, 500])
blue = [230, 242, 255]
screen.fill(blue)
pygame.display.update()
default = pygame.image.load("default.jpg")
screen.blit(default, (0,0))
pygame.display.update()
click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
#BASIC HEXAPAWN

#ALL POSSIBLE COMPUTER'S MOVE BOARDS AS ARRAY HERE
#TThe moves from the board images are left to right
class Board:
  def __init__(self, board, moves):
      self.board = board
      self.moves = moves

boards1 = [pygame.image.load("a1.jpg"), pygame.image.load("a2.jpg"),       pygame.image.load("a3.jpg")] #move1 boards
#irrelevant stuff removed, just initialising the other boards.

#GAME MAIN LOOP
while True:
  #START GAME - 1st move
  print("You play as O, computer is X")
  currentboard = "O O O\n# # #\nX X X"
  print(currentboard)

  #PLAYER MOVE 1
  screen.blit(boards1[0], (0, 250))
  pygame.display.update()
  if boards1[0].get_rect().collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()) and click:
    screen.blit(boards1[0], (0,0))
    pmove = 0
#note: I haven't added the other board options yet.

  currentboard = boards1[pmove]

#[insert more unnecessary code here]
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      pygame.quit()
  break
pygame.quit()
```

Basically whenever I run the code, the Pygame window looks alright, but when I try to click on the image it just stops responding. Also the window is always stuck on a loading cursor, idk why.

I've tried everything I could find but, nope, not working.

If anyone can help then I'd appreciate it.

Thanks :)

Eleeza

edit:i didnt know others could edit my posts too
Clearing some stuff up, when I ran my code, there were no errors, no `Traceback` the only problem is the unresponsive thing.

Also sorry im really bad at explaining things :/

Comment: when I run your code I see a `currentboard = boards1[pmove]
NameError: name 'pmove' is not defined` exception in the Traceback. you need to declare the `pmove` variable outside of the `for` loop, e.g. 1st line in your game loop. that should get you started

Comment: If Windows is reporting that your program is not working, that means you're not handling the events correctly. Can you reduce your issue to a [mcve] as that will make it easier for folks to help you? It may also be helpful to reorganise your game loop as described [here](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/pygame.html). Basically Event handling⟶Update State⟶Update Display.

Comment: @smoggers `pmove` is already outside the `for` loop. When I ran it there were no errors... I wonder what happened.

Comment: I just noticed a `pmove = 0` in the post...that wasn't there before. I should check that out

Comment: yeah sorry i meant outside the `if` statement not the `for` loop

Comment: @smoggers it didn't change anything. `pmove` is already initialised above the `if` statement. The reason `pmove = 0` is there is to change its value if an image is clicked. Yeah...…….I really need to work on how I explain things im honestly so bad at it :/

Comment: Oooookay: I have tried _everything_ and I mean  _**everything**_ that I could possibly find and the pygame window is still not responding...anyone else have the same problem?? :'(

Comment: Also, have any of these responses worked for anyone else? Because if so, I've got some other problem with it to fix.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things going on, but the main one is that you have you `click` variable set only once when the program starts.

Move `click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` inside of the main loop.
If you do that and it still hangs, you should show the rest of your code.

Also, the full code is not there, so I can't be 100% sure, but I don't think that `break` should be there.

Comment: Hello (wow i've never gotten a response so quickly on a forum before), I tried your solution, but when I tried to run it, I got the same problem :/ also the reason I didn't put the full code was that it was just irrelevant and didn't affect the problem in any way. I thought that the problem was to do  with an infinite loop so I put the `break` there, that didn't work. But thanks for your response anyway.